# How to do math with numbers and units in a command

Tags: tables, multicolumn, calculations

I want to create a 2-column wide table, that can change the width of the individual cells each row (in 5mm increments).

My Problem:

I'm trying to multiply a length (5mm) by an argument number.
Also I need to subtract this argument from 18, but all I get is errors.

I wrote down what I mean, I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tableLine}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{|p{6*5mm}|}{#2} & \multicolumn{18-#1}{|p{(18-#1)*5mm}|}{#3}\\ \hline}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{| *{18}{l|}}
        \hline
        \tableLine{6}{Left}{Right}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix the arithmetic of numbers and dimensions. So you need to make use of `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr` where needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tableLine}[3]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{ |p{#1\dimexpr5mm}| }{#2} &
    \multicolumn{\numexpr18-#1}{ |p{\numexpr(18-#1)\dimexpr5mm}| }{#3} \\
  \hline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| *{18}{l|} }
  \hline
  \tableLine{6}{Left}{Right}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, here is a definition using [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) that can handle numbers and dimensions interchangeably:

```
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\tableLine}[3]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{ |p{\inteval{#1*5mm}}| }{#2} &
    \multicolumn{\inteval{18-#1}}{ |p{\inteval{(18-#1)*5mm}}| }{#3} \\
  \hline}
```

Comment: `\dimexpr 5mm*(#1)` and `\dimexpr 5mm*(18-#1)` work as well

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. The key is to place a dimension *first*.